# Looks like the String type no longer provides contentsOfURL initializer anymore (after Xcode 7 update)?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

This worked in Xcode 6, but broke on the new update:

```
if var url = String(contentsOfURL: request.URL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

Gives me this error now. Having trouble finding an easy way to fix (if there is any):

"Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(contentsOfURL: NSURL?, encoding: UInt, error: NilLiteralConvertible)'

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift 2.0, the error has been removed and the `String` initializer now *throws* the error, which must be caught with `catch`. Alternatively, you can use `try?` to have it return an optional that is `nil` is there is an error.

In Swift 2.0, this does the same:

```
if var url = try? String(contentsOfURL: request.URL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

The `try?` returns a `String?` which the optional binding `if var` unwraps.

Comment: interesting, so it was the error parameter that is causing the issue? (or perhaps my approach to the error handling...)

Answer (score 2):

That is because Swift 2.0 has brand new error handling.

You can do it like so:

```
if let urlContent = try? String(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    // ...   
}
```

Or if you want to throw custom error:

```
guard let urlContent = try String(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    throw CustomError.CanNotLoadContentsOfURL
}
```

where `CustomError` is:

```
enum CustomError: ErrorType {
    case CanNotLoadContentsOfURL
}
```